# I configured the TestNG tests in parallel, but it is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

How can I debug this?

Follow SuiteTest.xml (TestNG is this way - Fix in the snippet "thread-count =" 2 "parallel =" tests "):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="SuiteTest" thread-count="2" parallel="tests">

<!-- classes tests methods  -->

    <test name="Firefox Test">

        <parameter name="browser" value="FIREFOX" />

        <classes>

            <class name="test.CN01_CT01_IncluirConteudoMP3" />

            <class name="test.CN01_CT02_IncluirConteudoMP4" />

        </classes>

    </test>

</suite>
```

Class DriveFactory:

```
public class DriverFactory {

    static String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {

        @Override

        protected synchronized WebDriver initialValue() {

            return initDriver();

        }

    };

    private DriverFactory() {

    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {

        return threadDriver.get();

    }

    public static WebDriver initDriver() {

        WebDriver driver = null;

        switch (Propriedades.browser) {

        case CHROME:

            //executeChrome(BasePage.url);

            break;

        case FIREFOX:

            String driverpathFirefox = path + File.separator + "drivers" + File.separator + "geckodriver.exe";

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverpathFirefox);

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            getDriver().get(BasePage.url);

            break;

        }

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        return driver;

    }


    public static void killDriver() {

        WebDriver driver = getDriver();

        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
            driver = null;
        }

        if (threadDriver != null) {
            threadDriver.remove();
            }

    }
}
```

Testing classes (Very simple to summarize the question):

```
public class CN01_CT02_IncluirConteudoMP4 extends BaseTest {

    @Test

    public void CN01_CT02_IncluirConteudoMp4(){

        assertEquals("123", "123");

    }

}

public class CN01_CT01_IncluirConteudoMP3 extends BaseTest {

    @Test

    public void CN01_CT01_IncluirConteudoMp3() throws InterruptedException, AWTException{

        assertEquals("123", "123456");

    }

}
```

BaseTest Class (Here I log in, log out and close the browser):

```
public class BaseTest {

    protected static ExtentReports extent;

    public static String testName;



    @Parameters({ "browser" })

    @BeforeMethod

    public void BeforeTest(Method method, Browsers browser) throws IOException, BiffException {

        Propriedades.browser = browser;

        String browserStr = browser.toString();




        //TestName

        testName = method.getName() + "-" + browserStr;



        // Login

        LoginPage.realizarLogin();

        //Start report

        extent = ExtentReport.StartReport(testName);    

    }

    @AfterMethod

    public void finaliza(ITestResult result) throws IOException {


        ExtentReport.ResultTest(result, testName);



        // Logout

        LoginPage.realizarLogout();

        // Closed Browser

        if (Propriedades.FECHAR_BROWSER) {

            killDriver();

        }

    }

    @AfterSuite

    public static void finalizaTudo(){

        DriverFactory.killDriver();

        extent.flush();

    }

}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<build>

    <testSourceDirectory>src</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>2.18.1</version>

            <configuration>

                <includes>

                    <include>/suites/SuiteTest.xml</include>

                </includes>

                <parallel>tests</parallel>

                <threadCount>1</threadCount>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>

        (..)
```

I have the BasePage class that only instantiates the DSL, this one at a time has the actions on the screen elements.

When running via Eclipse (Suite.xml - Run -> TestNG), the system opens several browsers and is not performing certain actions.

Comment: (Please use the preview window when posting here. The editor requires a minimal understanding of Markdown, which is the native format in nearly all tech tools you will use - Stack Overflow, Reddit, GitHub, Bitbucket, etc. Code needs to be block-formatted using backtick code gates or indentation, and lines starting with a hyphen `- ` will be treated as a bullet point - and this changes how subsequent code is formatted).

Answer (score 1):

Your test violates [Parallel Testing Best Practices](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices) and your tests will not be parallel at all due to [`synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) nature of the WebDriver usage.

The workaround would be to run your tests using a separate JVM instance for each tests, in *pom.xml* add the next lines:

```
<forkCount>2</forkCount>
<reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
```

A better approach would be re-writing your test to get rid of [static](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java) modifiers and synchronized methods.

More information: [Fork Options and Parallel Test Execution](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html)

Comment: I tried the solution below:

<forkCount> 2 </ forkCount>
<reuseForks> false </ reuseForks>

And it did not work ..

:(

Comment: The code before the changes to try running in parallel

The code before the changes to try running in parallel

private static WebDriver driver;

private DriverFactory () {
}

public static WebDriver getDriver () {

if (driver == null) {
switch (Properties.browser) {
case CHROME:
executeChrome (BasePage.url);
break;
case FIREFOX:
executeFirefox (BasePage.url);
break;
}
driver.manage (). window (). maximize ();
}

return driver;
}